# regex to replace words with more than two consecutive characters

Tags: regex, string, r, character

How can I detect the presence of more than two consecutive characters in a word and remove that word?

I seem to be able to do it like this:

```
# example data
mystring <- c(1, 2, 3, "toot", "tooooot")
# clunky regex
gsub("^[[:alpha:]]$", "", gsub(".*(.)\\1+\\1", "", mystring)) 
[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "toot" ""
```

But I'm sure there is a more efficient way. How can I do it with just one `gsub`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grepl` instead.

```
mystring <- c(1, 2, 3, "toot", "tooooot", "good", "apple", "banana")
mystring[!grepl("(.)\\1{2,}", mystring)]
## [1] "1"      "2"      "3"      "toot"   "good"   "apple"  "banana"
```

** Explanation**
`\\1` matches first group (in this case `(.)` ). `{2,}` specifies that preceding character should be matched atleast 2 times or more. Since we want to match any character repeated 3 times or more - `(.)` is first occurrence, `\\1` needs to be matched 2 times ore more.

Comment: This appears to be spot on, not returning anything at all in place of the word with more than two consecutive characters. Thanks!

Comment: Great response.  Would you care to explain a bit?  I get what all the pieces are doing except `\\1`

Answer (score 4):

Combine the expressions like so:

```
gsub("^[[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]])\\1\\1[[:alpha:]]*$", "", mystring)
```

Comment: three or more is the same as more than two...?

Comment: @Aquillo - Oh, my mistake. I read the title as "two or more" on autopilot. Editing answer, thanks.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating look-back. A simpler pattern might be: `".+([[:alpha:]])\\1\\1.+"`

Comment: @DWin - Thanks. Hm, I was trying to combine his two expressions into one--one of them checked for all-`[[:alpha:]]`, so I couldn't use `.+` on either end.

Comment: I didn't see a requirement for all alpha.

Answer (score 0):

An other possibility :

```
mystring[grepl("(.{1})\\1{2,}", mystring, perl=T)] <- ""
```

Comment: Yes, an interesting variation on @geektrader's answer, thanks